# while retrieving data from WHMCS API I'm getting error as follows : InvalidArgumentException View [SME_Hosting] not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have created a controller and the coding in my controller file is as shown below

This is the **controller code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use DarthSoup\Whmcs\Facades\Whmcs;
use DarthSoup\Whmcs\WhmcsServiceProvider;
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
  public function show(){
    $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([

    ]);
    return view('SME_Hosting',['products'=>$products]);
    }}
```

This is my Route

```
Route::get('/SME_Hosting','GetProductController@show');
```

I'm getting same error even after clearing the cache by using the below functions:
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan config:clear

Comment: What is your view file name ?? is it SME_hosting.balde.php??

Comment: Please check your view file name (i.e SME_Hosting)

Comment: Thank you so much it's fixed